# Symfony not loading runtime Twig extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I followed the example on [Symfony 3.4 docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/twig_extension.html#creating-lazy-loaded-twig-extensions) in order to load a Twig extension at runtime but it doesn't load: what I'am doing wrong?

**IN: src/PlotlyBundle/Twig/AppRuntime.php**

```
<?php
namespace PlotlyBundle\Twig;

class AppRuntime
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function biDraw()
    {
        return 'awesome text here';
    }
}
```

**IN: src/PlotlyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    plotly.twig_runtime:
        class: PlotlyBundle\Twig\AppRuntime
        public: true
        tags:
            - { name: twig.runtime }
```

**IN: src/PlotlyBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php**

```
<?php
namespace PlotlyBundle\Twig;

use PlotlyBundle\Twig\AppRuntime;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {    
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction(
                'bi_draw',
                array(AppRuntime::class, 'biDraw')
            ),
        ];
    }
}
```

**IN: src/AppBundle/Controller/DashboardController.php**

```
   $twig = $this->get('plotly.twig_runtime');
    return $this->render(
        'dashboard/index.html.twig'
    );
```

**IN: app/Resources/views/dashboard/index.html.twig**

```
{{ bi_draw() }}
```

Comment: That's doesn't feel right.. isn't the documentation wrong? Can you try with `class: PlotlyBundle\Twig\AppExtension`?

Comment: ^ no, it's not wrong -- are you auto-wiring it? otherwise you need to tag it with `twig.extension`

Comment: I already tried: when using xdebug I see the constructor is called but the getFunctions is not called.. Should I add a dependency injection to my bundle (PlotlyBundle)?

Comment: I added the tag in the service.yml

Comment: Can you update your post with it? Have your service container's autoconfigure option enabled? ( https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container.html#the-autoconfigure-option )

Comment: If I use twig.extension as a tag it works but still don't understand why the tag twig.runtime doesn't

Comment: `twig.runtime` is meant for lazy loading. You can keep it. Problem was that you didn't registered the twig extension at all to begin with.

Comment: hmm.. I follwed that example on the docs and since xdebug breakpoint on the AppExtension constructor triggers => the extension is regestered.. I don't figure out what I am missing :( maybe the default AppBundle does some extra work that the PlotlyBundle doesn't?

Comment: It wasn't registered. Constructor was called because you called it in your  controller with `$twig = $this->get('plotly.twig_runtime');`. At that point you created the `AppRuntime` object. I guess the sy doc just assume that you have the `autoconfigure` option enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171907/discussion-between-numediaweb-and-federkun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Federkun comments I fixed it by autowiring the Twig extension:

**IN: src/PlotlyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    PlotlyBundle\Twig\:
        resource: '../../../../src/PlotlyBundle/Twig/*'
        tags:
            - { name: twig.runtime }
```

The example on the Symfony docs ([Creating Lazy-Loaded Twig Extensions](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/twig_extension.html#creating-lazy-loaded-twig-extensions)) need an update to mention that auto-wiring **MUST** be enabled (as explained in the [autoconfigure Option](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container.html#the-autoconfigure-option)) in order for the example to work.

I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/9841) to the Symfony docs.

Comment: Tagging all services of the `Twig` subnamespace as `twig.runtime` is not the right solution. Most of these services are not runtimes, but extensions.

And the reason for it to fix your issue is that you are now registering your extension as a service (and tagged as an extension thanks to autoconfiguration), which was not done in your original config.